# ng-model in select box with default value is empty

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-options

I am trying to use `ng-model` to get value from the selection tag with Angular js.  However, when I render this code, the selected box is empty when the page finished loading.  I tried to set the first option to be selected, but that doesn't work.   I tried `selected="selected"` but doesn't work.  I also tried other methods mentioned in documentation about ng-option but it doesn't seem to help.  I NEED the ng-model value in order for other parts of my page to work.

`<select id="teamSelection" ng-model="teamSelected">
          <option value="All" selected>All</option>
          <option value="1">A</option>
          <option value="2)">B</option>
          <option value="3">C</option>
          <option value="4">D</option>
        </select>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem earlier this week.  The fix is actually simpler than I thought.  You can just add a `ng-init="teamSelected='All'"` as an attribute to your select tag:

`<select id="teamSelection" ng-model="teamSelected" ng-init="teamSelected='All'">
          <option value="All" selected>All</option>
          <option value="1">A</option>
          <option value="2)">B</option>
          <option value="3">C</option>
          <option value="4">D</option>
        </select>`

Answer (score 2):

Set you `$scope.teamSelected = 3` (index of the desired object)  for example, and it should work fine like in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/bobleujr/pen/vNBQPW)

Comment: beware of the index when using `track by`